# не меняется фон у кнопки при наведении C#

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Button x:Name="addRoom" Content="" Margin="0,0,0,-1" Click="add_room_click" Height="22" Width="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
     <Button.Style>
          <Style TargetType="Button" >
              <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                   </Trigger>
                   <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                          Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCDCDCD" />
                   </Trigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </Button.Style>
      <Button.Background>
           <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/plus_icon.png"/>
      </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

не срабатывает ни один из тригеров.. цвет кнопка при наведении цвет меняет, но она меняет на другой, какой был задан по умолчанию, как я понял. Меняет она его не смотря на изображение, она просто это изображение убирает и ставит свой цвет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, как задан стиль кнопки. Его можно посмотреть в Visual Studio 2015, нажав на правую кнопку мыши в дизайнере и выбрав «Edit Template...». Вы увидите, что для показа другого цвета при наведении мыши используется триггер внутри шаблона, который выставляет фиксированный цвет, не зависящий от `Background`:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Обратите внимание на эту часть:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Это значит, что для смены цвета на `IsMouseOver` имеет смысл подменить `Button.MouseOver.Background`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="Green"/>
```

К сожалению, это значит, что вам придётся тащить с собой весь стиль, т. к. `Button.MouseOver.Background` подключается как `StaticResource`.

---

Я отредактировал ответ, старый ответ оказался неправильным.

Comment: логично.. но почему фон у кнопки тогда меняется? а именно изображение убирается при наведении

Comment: залил [скрин при наведении](http://www.fotolink.su/v.php?id=5dccaacd238d0ae877065b1b7f550409)

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть полезно:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnOpen">

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="4">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00FFFFFF"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```